# Checking if a user has left a server discord js

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make a leaderboard for how long people are in voice chat but when people leave the server and are still in the database it causes a type error as it cannot read that user's id in the server and so i tried

```js
if (!client.guilds.cache.get(serverid).members.cache.get(user)){
    continue
}
```

to skip out people who were not in the server but this caused another type error: `TypeError: Cannot read property '281377425215062016' of undefined` and i'm not sure how to fix this, any help would be appreciated.

```js
for (const user in VoiceDatabase[serverid]){
    if (!client.guilds.cache.get(serverid).members.cache.get(user)){continue}
    if (user == "Servername"){continue}
    templeaderboard.push(VoiceDatabase[serverid][user].TotalXP)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `guildMemberRemove` to get when user left the server

```js
client.on('guildMemberRemove', async member => {

});
```

Such as get member when left console.log -> read username of user left

```js
client.on('guildMemberRemove', async member => {
  console.log(member.user.username)
});
```

### Reference

- [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)
- [GuildMemberRemove](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberRemove)